# Unable to run Java project suddenly. Error 404 in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have attached my project's folder tree view in the screenshot below

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Is there any mistake in it ? Yesterday I was still able to run it, today it's giving me enormous amount of errors.

Edited--

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace you're receiving?  Is the error when you are building the project or deploying?

Comment: When I clicked on the button in my html page, it says ClasNotFound at first and then the second time I clicked, it says, the requested resoucre is not found @randal4

Comment: which `ClassNotFound`?

Comment: one example is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. But yesterday and the days before yesterday, it was working fine until today.

Comment: Did you add all the required jars to classpath.

Comment: add mysql driver to the lib folder

Comment: I have added them in the lib folder. See screenshot 3 @Ramanlfc

Comment: Could you add full error log ?

Comment: Hey guys, I got it working by deleting everything in the lib folder and importing it back again. Anyone knows whats the cause of this ?